# Logic behind MDN's reduce() pollyfill's while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

The `Array.prototype.reduce()` polyfill [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill):

```
Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback /*, initialValue*/) {
  'use strict';
  var t = this, len = t.length, k = 0, value;

  //IF initial value provided - go to the for loop
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
  value = arguments[1];
  } 
  else { 
    while (k < len && !(k in t)) {
      k++; 
    } 
    //IF no values then THROW a TYPEERROR
    if (k >= len) {
      throw new TypeError('Reduce of empty array with no initial value');
    }
    value = t[k++];
  }

  for (; k < len; k++) {
    if (k in t) {
    value = callback(value, t[k], k, t);
    }
  }
  return value;
};
```

Questions:

1. What is the `else`...`while` part of the script doing? What is the logic behind it? I thought it had to do with being supplied additional initial value arguments. But the `t` here is the array context not the method's argument context. It seems to be doing a same job as the `for` loop.
2. What's the logic of the `(k in t)` expression here? Why would it be checking the iterator value against the actual array values?

   ```
   else {
     while (k < len && !(k in t)) {
       k++; 
     }
     if (...) {
      ...
     }
     value = t[k++];
   }
   ```

Comment: looks like it counts the number of slot in the array, which is kinda dumb for non-sparse arrays...

Comment: It's skipping missing elements in sparse arrays. similar to: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/BoYvva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1 finds a *valid*, *existing* initial value (if one wasn't already supplied). In a sparse array, you can't just assume that `array[0]` was set.

If we declare:

```
var sparse = [];
sparse[1] = "something";
sparse[4] = "else";
```

then `sparse[0]` isn't a real value, and won't be `in sparse`.

You need to find the first value that was actually set. The first index that's `in` the array.

So, starting with `k == 0`:

```
while (k < len && !(k in t)) {
  k++; 
}
```

we look through the array until we find an index that's "real".  In our example, that will be `sparse[1]`.

If we didn't find one, the next `if` throws an error.

Otherwise,

```
value = t[k++];
```

we have our initial value, and move on.

Part 2 loops through the rest of the *actual* elements of the array, calling the callback for each, and skipping "missing" indices:

```
for (; k < len; k++) {
  if (k in t) {            
    value = callback(value, t[k], k, t);
  }
}
```

In our example, `2` and `3` are skipped, and we next call the callback for `sparse[4]`.

If the array isn't sparse (e.g. `var arr = [1,2,3,4];`) this all works fine, it just doesn't skip anything.

Comment: okay thx for the clear answer - will have time i a bit to workto get my head around - be back thx

Comment: great 2 quick follow ups: 1. `value = t[k++];`   why the k++? don't we have the k value that we need to start with from the while loop just with `value = t[k]` ?  2. This  would not work on an associative array, i am assuming? Thnx agian.

Comment: never mind - i got it - k++ would go start with the `next` value in the array to be reduced with the initial value that was already established - that is why the for loop doesn't initialiise the k value. Go it thanks.